# How to get raven to report Django runscript exceptions to Sentry?

Tags: django, sentry, raven

My Django web app logs exceptions to Sentry via raven. I also run a number of scripts (via `manage.py runscript`) as cron jobs. Right now any exceptions in those scripts are not being reported to Sentry. How do I set such reporting up?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 5.3.1 of raven-python it should correctly patch Django's BaseCommand.execute, which effectively will handle errors in these commands (unless that parent call is never made).

Comment: Ah that sounds great, I'm using an old version. Will come back and accept answer once I confirm that works.

Answer (score 0):

For those out there that:

1. still have an issue of raven not patching itself for django management commands correctly
2. have Django==1.6.11
3. haven raven==5.12.0

I have found a fix that works for me.

The problem seems to be that raven is not patching `BaseCommand.execute` by the time it is called by Django. So to fix that, I make sure `BaseCommand.execute` is patched right away. I've updated my `manage.py` file to include the following lines:

```
from raven.contrib.django.management import patch_cli_runner
patch_cli_runner()
```

My final `manage.py` file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os.path import abspath
from os.path import dirname
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
# add the ../ directory to the os path, so that we can find
# app.settings below
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), '..')))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
from raven.contrib.django.management import patch_cli_runner
patch_cli_runner()

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```